# How can I load from a json file faster into my datatables?

Tags: php, json, datatables, server-side

This is my json file 
(with 5000 items):

```
{
    "data": [{
            "name": "file1.html",
            "date": "2019-01-29T20:33:57.00163Z",
            "size": "348"
        },
        {
            "name": "file2.xml",
            "date": "2019-01-29T20:33:57.000167Z",
            "size": "401"
        },
        {
            "name": "file3.html",
            "date": "2019-01-29T20:33:57.000171Z",
            "size": "1314"
        }
    ]

}
```

I am loading it like this:

```
var table = $('.table').DataTable({
  "pageLength": 10,
  "data":{{ output.data|raw }},
```

But it is really really slowly, it takes 10seconds until the datatable is loaded on my page.

So I tried the server-side method:

```
var table = $('.table').DataTable({
    "pageLength": 10,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "{{ absolute_url(asset('files/data.json')) }}",
```

But now the loading is even slower...
And the pagination is not working anymore.

Is there any chance to speed up the performance?

Comment: Are you using serverside pagination?

Comment: @Sreeraj_ms I am not sure

Comment: @Sreeraj_ms I tried `"paging": true,` but stil slowly

Comment: In both server side and client side your doing same process.You just loading json file.Not using any pagination concept .try to load your data with pagination concept

Comment: @dhamo I was researching about it, but I couldn't find a an example for a pagination concept, so I am not sure how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are dealing with client-side large datasets (by large i define as over 1000) , you would probably want to switch to the Server-side implementation of data for your datatables data.

```
table = $('#example').DataTable( {
serverSide: true,
deferLoading: 57
ajax: {
  url:"files/data.json",
  },
 });
```

[Datatables Server-Side Documentation](https://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/)

[Pipeline data for reducing ajax call on pagination](https://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html)

Comment: I have just edit the answer, you can follow the pipeline concept for reducing the ajax call for pagination.

Comment: Thank you! I tested your code. The datatable loads fast, but without content . `No matching records found`

Comment: I just tested your pipline suggestion and it works!! `"processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": $.fn.dataTable.pipeline( {
          url: '{{ absolute_url(asset('files/test.json')) }}',
          pages: 5 // number of pages to cache
    }),` The datatable is loaded fast.

Comment: The only problem is, that the search is not working anymore and the total entries are not shown correctly `(filtered from NaN total entries)`

Comment: Let me check and get back to you.

Comment: Ok, I solved one of the problems. the total entries are shown when I add in my json file at the beginning: `{
  "draw": 1,
 "recordsTotal": 5000,
 "recordsFiltered": 5000,
    "data": [`

Comment: I just need to check the problem with the "search"